# iOS: Is NSUserDefaults synced with iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, icloud

Apple's review team that reviews my app claims that large amounts of data are backed by iCloud (this data shouldn't be backed). So I'm trying to figure out which files are responsible for it. Maybe it's the plist that holds NSUserDefaults?
Does iCloud backup NSUserDefaults?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing NSUserDefaults from iCloud Backup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981973/preventing-nsuserdefaults-from-icloud-backup)

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults really can't be too large to be the reason of your rejection. Also, they are not backed up.

I would advise you to check your Documents Folder - this is what is really backed up to iCloud.

Comment: According to this link the library folder is partly backed up http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9

Comment: Ok, so what?I said nothing about Library

Comment: Hi Alex, did you figure out the problem? I have the same issue and believe my NSUserDefault gets backup by iCloud, but couldn't find a way to fix it. Can you advise me of any solution? THanks