# Preventing NSUserDefaults from iCloud Backup

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, icloud

There are three ways to write persistently to the device in iOS that I'm aware of:

1. NSUserDefaults
2. Custom Objects - Archived and Written to a PATH in NSDocuments
3. SQLite

Apple provide a mechanism to prevent iCloud backups with #2 i.e.

`- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL`

I use NSUserDefaults to store three images but to adhere to iOS Data Storage Guidelines -
How do I prevent Backups with iCloud with NSUserDefaults?

This question has been asked several times on SO but there is no clear comprehensive answer yet.

Is there a such a function or do I have to change storing images using method #2. I was hoping something convenient like:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackAttributeForStandardUserDefaultsKey:(NSString *)
```

exists.

Comment: Your approach seems little bit weird. Why can't you store image to document directory ? Why you need to do that in NSUserdefaults ?

Comment: I can of course retrofit my code to adhere to the mechanism in #2 but I was hoping for a an easier way similar to how #2 prevents iCloud Backups. What seems odd that apples mechanism for storing data can't adhere to it's own guidelines. I'll just assume there is something I don't understand yet or a piece of information I missed somewhere learning iOS.  Perhaps storing Images with NSUserDefaults is a bad idea but I don't see why.

Comment: NSUserdefaults can be used for storing a few amount of data, that controls the app behavior or storing the app configuration keys etc. You can add images to the document directory and use `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL` for skipping iCloud backup. There is no such mechanism like `addSkipBackAttributeForStandardUserDefaultsKey` for preventing the NSUserDefaults data. It'll be backed up automatically, since it contains user specific data like user settings and user configurations.

Comment: Midhun MP: NSUserDefaults works very well for storing images and other arbitrary data. I have used it successfully for several years with no problems. I rarely need to save to NSDocumentDirectory or anywhere else.

Comment: Can someone clarify: from my reading of the docs, NSUserDefaults is only persisted to the local device (and possibly to iCloud for devices set up for educational use), and if you want a variant of NSUserDefaults that DOES sync to iCloud, you should use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore. Is this understanding correct, or are there other (non-education) cases where NSUserDefaults persists to iCloud?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no mechanism for this. `NSUserDefaults` is not intended to be used for saving app data. It's there to hold user preferences and other settings the app needs, but isn't intended as a full data persistence system.

It's not accurate to say that this *"...[Apple's] mechanism for storing data can't adhere to it's own guidelines"* because that's not the purpose of this API. In this case specifically, if those images should not be backed up, then that's absolute evidence that user defaults is the wrong place to store them.

You should save the images to files. If you have `UIImage`, this is simple. `UIImage` conforms to `NSCoding`, so it's easy to convert to/from an `NSData`. And `NSData` includes convenience methods to read/write objects to files. If the file names might change, you could reasonably put the file names in user defaults. If the file names are known in advance and can't change, then there's no reason to store them.

Comment: "You should save the images to files" - Just because images often are saved one by one to files does not really make it a reason why an app must always save images to files. Image data or sound data or whatever other kinds of data is just *data* and the only thing an app cares about is that it is persisted and that it can be accessed again. NSUserDefaults works for any kind of data which is why it specifically supports NSData. If said data should not be backed up, NSUserDefaults obviously does not support this, but there is no correlation to the type of data, image, sound or what not.

Comment: I was writing specifically in response to a question about preventing data from being backed up to iCloud, not writing a general treatise on how to save data. In this situation the data should be written to files because **that is how you prevent it from being backed up to iCloud**.